# ejecutar archivo .yml

Tags: windows, cmd, docker, docker-compose

Tengo un problema al intentar ejecutar un archivo yml desde cmd (versión Windows 10.0.18362.1082)

Lo tengo ubicado es esta dirección:

> C:\Users\Paula\Desktop\ejecutar\docker-compose.yml

Lo intento ejecutar:

> cd C:\Users\Paula\Desktop\ejecutar\docker-compose.yml

Pero el sistema me responde con: `El nombre del directorio no es válido`

Si hago:

> C:\Users\Paula\Desktop\ejecutar>docker-compose

Me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien me pudiese ayudar lo agradecería mucho

Comment: ¿que sucede si haces `cd C:\Users\Paula\Desktop\ejecutar` y luego `docker-compose up`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Lo intento ejecutar:
>
> > cd C:\Users\Paula\Desktop\ejecutar\docker-compose.yml
>
> Pero el sistema me responde con: El nombre del directorio no es válido

El comando `cd` (change directory) lo que hace es cambiar el directorio de tabajo actual por el que se le pasa como parámetro. Este error se debe a que en vez de un directorio de estás pasando un archivo como parámetro.

> Si hago:
>
> C:\Users\Paula\Desktop\ejecutar>docker-compose
>
> Me devuelve lo siguiente:
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema aquí es que no le dices a `docker-compose` que ejecute ningún comando, por lo que te muestra su ayuda para que veas el modo de usarlo correctamente.

Para desplegar los contenedores definidos en tu archivo `docker-compose.yml` puedes usar una de estas dos opciones:

1. Desde el directorio que contiene el `docker-compose.yml`

```
C:\Users\Paula\Desktop\ejecutar> docker-compose up -d
```

2. Desde cualquier directorio

```
C:\> docker-compose -f C:\Users\Paula\Desktop\ejecutar\docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Comment: muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Un placer ayudarte @Pau! Saludos.